# Jamroot (boost-bjam) linking with shared libraries

Tags: python, c++, boost, shared-libraries, bjam

I am using Jamroot/boost-bjam to build a python binding for C++ code:

```
alias boost_dependencies
  : /boost/python//boost_python
    /boost/thread//boost_thread
  ;


# Platform architecture provided as an environment variable
import os ; 
local ARCH = [ os.environ ARCH ] ;

# Set up the project-wide requirements that everything uses the
# boost_python library from the project whose global ID is
# /boost/python.
project
  : requirements <library>boost_dependencies
                 <include>../
                 <include>../../
  : requirements 
                 <library-path>../../thirdparty/opencv/lib/
                 <linkflags>-lm 
                 <linkflags>-lpthread
                 <linkflags>-lcrypto
                 <linkflags>-lssl
  ;

# Declare the three extension modules.  You can specify multiple
# source files after the colon separated by spaces.
python-extension test_library : src/Test.cpp
```

I would like to link with shared libraries in opencv project (../../thirdparty/opencv/lib/) such as libopencv_core.dylib, libopencv_video.dylib etc. on mac. How do I specify the libraries in the Jamroot file and also install them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem using lib option:

```
lib opencv_core : : <name>libopencv_core <search>../../thirdparty/opencv/build/$(ARCH)/lib/ ;
lib opencv_video : : <name>libopencv_video <search>../../thirdparty/opencv/build/$(ARCH)/lib/ ;
lib opencv_ml : : <name>libopencv_ml <search>../../thirdparty/opencv/build/$(ARCH)/lib/ ;
lib opencv_imgproc : : <name>libopencv_imgproc <search>../../thirdparty/opencv/build/$(ARCH)/lib/ ;
lib opencv_objdetect : : <name>libopencv_objdetect <search>../../thirdparty/opencv/build/$(ARCH)/lib/ ;

# Set up the project-wide requirements that everything uses the
# boost_python library from the project whose global ID is
# /boost/python.
project
  : requirements <library>boost_dependencies
                 <include>../
                 <include>../../
  : requirements <library>../../Common/build/$(ARCH)/lib/libCommon.a
                 <library>../../Vision/build/$(ARCH)/lib/libVision.a
                 <library-path>../../thirdparty/opencv/build/$(ARCH)/lib/
                 <library>../../thirdparty/opencv/build/$(ARCH)/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
                 <linkflags>-lopencv_core
                 <linkflags>-lopencv_video
                 <linkflags>-lopencv_ml
                 <linkflags>-lopencv_imgproc
                 <linkflags>-lopencv_objdetect
  ;
```